# How do I fill empty fields based on the most common value of the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and need a little help with this query:

```
UPDATE student
SET s.date_of_birth= SELECT count(*) max date_of_birth 
FROM student WHERE batch =st.batch
FROM student s, student st
WHERE st.date_of_birth IS NULL
```

All i need is to fill `date_of_birth` where it is empty by counting the most common `date_of_birth` of that batch. Given what I've shown, how can I do this?

Comment: looks like you have some code, so what's your question? (EDIT: for the record, I do see that your code is wrong, but it is important to be able to articulate exactly what your issue is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group on the date and sort on the count to get the most common date:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.date_of_birth = (
  SELECT top 1 date_of_birth
  FROM student
  WHERE batch = s.batch
  GROUP BY date_of_birth
  ORDER BY count(*) desc
)
FROM student s
WHERE s.date_of_birth IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down what you're trying to do. You want to find all of the `student`s who don't have a birthdate, and set their birthdate to whatever happens to be the most common birthdate in their batch. In sets the "most common" is referred to as the mode (you should remember "mean, median, and mode" from school).

So what you're trying to do is something like this (pseudocode):

```
UPDATE s
SET s.date_of_birth = (
    SELECT mode(date_of_birthday)
    FROM student 
    WHERE batch = s.batch
)
FROM student s
WHERE s.date_of_birth IS NULL
```

However, `mode` is not a function in sql server, so we'll have to create our own way of getting mode. Well, what is the mode if not just the highest frequency item? To that end, let's just get counts and only grab the largest one:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.date_of_birth = (
    SELECT TOP 1 date_of_birthday
    FROM student
    WHERE batch = s.batch
    GROUP BY date_of_birthday
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
)
FROM student s
WHERE s.date_of_birth IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question. You're trying to do a subquery in your SET statement but that's not how it works. If you want to do it dynamically, you need to first create the subquery and make sure it works. You want to select date_of_birth from student, you want the count of the values rather than the values themselves, you want to sort them by the count, and you want only the first row of that result. Therefore the subquery is:

```
select date_of_birth from student group by date_of_birth order by count(date_of_birth) desc limit 1;
```

Now you can simply put that into your update statement in place of the value:

```
SET s.date_of_birth=(select date_of_birth from student group by date_of_birth order by count(date_of_birth) desc limit 1)
```

But the value is a constant, so why run the query on every update statement? Just run that query first, get the result, and use it in your update query.

(In some cases, perhaps you'd want later updates to set the value differently based on previous updates, but in this case, the most frequently used DOB will simply be used more frequently, so the query will always return the same thing.)